# Android SQLite complex INSERT not working as expected

Tags: android, sqlite, insert, nested

I am currently developing an android app, where I have to import pretty large XML files to SQL. Previously I've had a INSERT for every single Element in the XML. Now I try to create a temporary SQL file, that gets imported, because that is lots way faster. Since the data is dynamic I've some Statements like this:

```
INSERT INTO About VALUES ('System Karteikasten', '', '[todo]', '[todo]', '[todo]', '[todo]', 'null');
INSERT INTO Collection (Collection_id, About_id, MediaFile_Id, type, isbn, releasedate, publisher, edition, description, priv_sortChilds, priv_createChild, priv_deleteChild, priv_insertChild) VALUES ('system_kalepro_main', (SELECT ROWID FROM About ORDER BY ROWID DESC LIMIT 1), 'null', 'CARDBOX', 'null', '0', 'null', 'null', 'Some Text', 'false', 'false', 'false', 'false');
```

Sometimes I've like 1000 of this groups. As you might have guessed from the SQL already there's a foreign key in Collection: About_id points to a ROWID from About. I've tested the whole code and everything works like expected on the linux machine. However it does not on my Android Phone, where only the About inserts work. Also there is no error, that could point me in the right direction. The Collection entry are simply ignored and I guess it has something to do with the nested query, but I can't figure out how to fix that.

Any Ideas or suggestions?

Comment: Try to use Navicat for SQLITE http://www.navicat.com/en/products/navicat_sqlite/sqlite_overview.html to debug your queries.

Comment: Have you tried surrounding your dynamic values with ' e.g.  
'"+Collection_id+"' ?

Comment: @Lemberg Can Navicat simulate the behaviour of Android? Because I've already debuged it on my local machine, where everything worked fine.

Comment: @Sadragos have you tried it on SQLITE DB? Navicat for SQLITE simulate only behaviour of SQLITE.

Comment: @Noloxs Don't know what you mean... The String is fully escaped in my Code, otherwise it would throw an error.

Comment: @Lemberg Yeah, I'm using the an exact copy of the sqlite.db of my app on my pc and have tested it with the commandline sqlite-client from ubuntu and the firefox-plugin SQLitemanager. They're both executing my querys as expected.

Comment: Don't know what to advice, maybe try to look in the Logcat sometimes there are many useful information.

Answer (score 0):

An `INSERT` does not silently fail; your code that executes the SQL commands is ignoring errors somewhere.

Anyway, as long as you have no more than one child record, you can replace the subquery with [`last_insert_rowid()`](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#last_insert_rowid).

Alternatively, try `(SELECT max(rowid) FROM About)`.

Comment: Thanks for the hint with the last_insert_rowid() - only knew that as a php-function until now. However neither last_insert_rowid() nor the SQL is working on the Android end. Both work on my local machine. And no, there are no error - neither on LogCat nor console. This is the code, where I'm executing the query:
    DatabaseHelper helper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
    SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
    try {
      db.execSQL(s);
        } catch (SQLiteException e) {
          System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    db.close()

Comment: `last_insert_rowid()` works only in the same database connection. You should use the same `db` for all commands.